# Grepping for PCI ID - String like this [10de:1c81]

Tags: grep

I'm trying to script setup for PCI GPU Passthrough w/ KVM on Linux. You need to find the pci device ID via the following,

```
root@kvmatrix:~# lspci -nn | grep VGA | grep NVIDIA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050] [10de:1c81] (rev a1)
```

I'd like to add another "grep" to only result in this part,

```
10de:1c81
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
lspci -nn  | grep -oP 'VGA.*NVIDIA.*\[\K[\w:]+'
```

or more portable (some old Linux OS don't have `-P` switch)

```
lspci -nn  | perl -lne 'print $& if /VGA.*NVIDIA.*\[\K[\w:]+/'
```

### Output :

```
10de:1c81
```

[LiveDemo](https://regex101.com/r/29nkKc/2) with explanations on the right

Comment: Perfect, I had a feeling somebody would improve on my double grep!

Comment: PS: Care to explain that grep statement, its like its magic to me :P

Comment: Check my added link

Comment: LiveDemo is really cool BTW, thats an easy way to save you time and show how this works, and also a good tool to show others!

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers: some old distros don't have `-P` switch. Post edited with another answer

Answer (score 3):

If you know what class of device it is that you're wanting to get, it's probably easier to use that instead. In this case, "VGA controller" is class `0300`, so you can tell `lspci` to only give you information about those:

```
$ lspci -nd::0300|egrep -o "[[:xdigit:]]{4}:[[:xdigit:]]{4}"
```

This is an `egrep` search, so you can also use `grep -E`. Because there's only one item that will ever match `xxxx:xxxx` (`x` being a hex digit), that's what I matched on.

If you had several video cards that could match and only wanted the nVidia one, you could do `lspci -nd10de::0300` to restrict it to only that vendor.

Comment: There is also the audio device, I like the "readability" of your egrep statement though.

Comment: Id select this as the answer for readability IF it could combine grepping for "VGA/NVIDIA" and searching for the PCI-ID. I want to start with lspci -nn. This allows me to easily add another line "Audio/NVIDIA" to find that controller as well.

Comment: You could do something like `egrep -o "[[:xdigit:]]{4}:[[:xdigit:]]{4}" <<< $(lspci -nd10de::0300; lspci -nd10d3::0403)` (`0403` is the class for audio devices.)

Answer (score 1):

Using [`discover`](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/discover/discover.1.en.html) : *hardware detection utility*

```
discover --vendor-id --model-id pci | grep NVIDIA | uniq | awk '{print $1":"$2}'
```

sample output:

```
10de:1c81
```

Comment: Not installed by default on arch